# Filtered replication from couchdb to pouchdb

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I need to replicate selected records from couchdb to pouchdb,

how to create filter in couchdb and use it in pouchdb ?

I am using Ionic.

Thanks

Comment: Have you searched a bit on Google? There are plenty of documentation about this. Have a look in this [one](https://pouchdb.com/2015/04/05/filtered-replication.html)

Comment: I did tried it but struggling to create same design document on couchdb

Comment: If you did try, next time post what you have try so we can figure out the problem together.

Answer (score 0):

Manage to resolve it, was making very stupid mistake.

here is how document will look like in cloudant

```
 {
  "_id": "_design/agentapp",
  "_rev": "2-ede711dde1923`enter code here`1092dd7bebc4c22811d",
  "filters": {
    "by_agent": "function(doc, req) { return doc.agent ===   req.query.agent;}"
  }
}
```

working curl request
https://host/database/_changes?filter=agentapp/by_agent&agent=1